# Top level element is not completed

Tags: android, search

I am trying to create a search interface. I have searched a lot and created xml folder in my res folder manually and placed searchable.xml file inside res/xml.
Now when i am trying to add this file in AndroidManifest.xml with code

It is showing me error with red-line under "@xml/searchable" and saying "Top level Element is not completed". How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That is part of a Navigation Drawer flow, (it isn't a menu and doesn't drop down).

As terrible as link only answers are, it's the only option here as I can't possibly cover it with the depth the developer docs do: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 0):

Gmail use material navigation drawer and this three bar is button to open navigation list......

Tutorial on material navigation [this](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html)

Github project : [this](https://github.com/AkashBang/NavigationView)

Comment: Please quote some important information from the links so your answer can still be helpfull if the links go down